# PHP - Pass a function into another function and call it

Tags: php, function, reference

Is it possible to pass a function to another function and then call it?
Example:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{       
    public function sayHello()
    {   
        echo "Hello";
    }

    public function sayBye()
    {   
        echo "Bye";
    }

    public function say($text)
    {
         if ($text === "Hello") {
                 $this->doChecks($text, $this->sayHello);
         }
         else {
                 $this->doChecks($text, $this->sayBye);
         }
    }

    public function doChecks($text, $callback)
    {
         if (is_string($text)) {
                 $callback();
         }
         else {
             echo "ERROR";
         }
    }
}
```

If you call `say()` like this `say('Hello')` then `sayHello()` should be executed, after the check in `doChecks()` were passed, otherwise (if $text is not a string) "**ERROR**" should be printed.

**What I get**: `Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\TestController::$sayHello`

If you call `say()` like this `say('somerandomstuff')` then `sayBye()` should be executed, after the check in `doChecks()` were passed, otherwise (if $text is not a string) "**ERROR**" should be printed.

**What I get**: `Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\TestController::$sayBye`

---

If I try to pass the functions address like this:

```
 public function doChecks($text, &$callback)
```

then I get `Function name must be a string`, if I output $callback with echo inside `doChecks` like this: `echo "'$callback'";` then I get ''

How does it work?

Comment: I still don't know what I have to change in my code to make it work.

Comment: I was able to solve it by replacing `$this->doChecks($text, $this->sayHello);` with `$this->doChecks($text, array($this, 'sayHello'));`

Comment: And `$this->doChecks($text, $this->sayBye);` with `$this->doChecks($text, array($this, 'sayBye'));`